# Count rows in variable range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, count, range, counting

I have established, in Excel VBA, a range biased off of the location of two values in a data set. The row numbers of the start and stop in the range will change with data entry so I needed to create a range that will always offset from a set area. I now need to count the number of rows/values in the range so that once I copy the data in the range I can then remove the duplicates without altering the original list. How can I count the number of rows in my range?

I have attempted to use `copyrange.Rows.Count` but got error 438

```
Sub count_ID_List()
    Set botrow = Cells.Find("Stud ID")
    'Finds the first row of the count section of the invitory'
    Set toprow = Cells.Find("Stud Part Number")
    'Finds the top row of the company invintory'
    Set copyrange = Range(toprow.Offset(1, 0).Address, botrow.Offset(-12, 1).Address)
    Set copyto = Range(botrow.Offset(1, 0), botrow.Offset(1, 0))
    copyrange.Copy (copyto)
    'this is where i would like to then remove duplicates from the newly copied data'
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to understand how you need to post questions in this community. This question needs more clarity and please format it according to SO guidelines for others to understand it clearly.

Comment: Have you stepped through to see what's going on? Any number of potential problems here but we're in the dark somewhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) you always need to test if something was found:

```
Set BotRow = Cells.Find("Stud ID")
If BotRow Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Stud ID was not found!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

- Always define the `LookAt` parameter in the find method otherwise Excel uses whatever was used before (by either a user or VBA).
- Specify for all `Cells` and `Range` objects in which worksheet they are.
- Use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables properly.

The following should work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub count_ID_List()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define your sheet name here

    'Finds the first row of the count section of the invitory'
    Dim BotRow As Range
    Set BotRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Stud ID", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If BotRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'Stud ID' was not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Finds the top row of the company invintory'
    Dim TopRow As Range
    Set TopRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Stud Part Number", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If TopRow Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'Stud Part Number' was not found!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim CopyRange As Range
    Set CopyRange = ws.Range(TopRow.Offset(1, 0), BotRow.Offset(-12, 1))

    Dim CopyTo As Range
    Set CopyTo = BotRow.Offset(1, 0)

    'output row count
    Debug.Print CopyRange.Rows.Count

    CopyRange.Copy Destination:=CopyTo

    'this is where i would like to then remove duplicates from the newly copied data'
    CopyTo.Resize(RowSize:=CopyRange.Rows.Count).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much I am new to doing anything with VBA and coding in general. This was great did exactly what I wanted and the notes at the top I will keep in mind.  Have a great day!